# The use of bitmasks in Objective-C: how iOS handles options stored in bitmasks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, bit-manipulation, bitmask

So, I started learning iOS development and Objective-C recently, mainly using Stanford's free course on iTunes U.

I ended up stumbling across bitmasks, something widely used in iOS APIs but that I'm not very familiar with. I've read some stuff about it and now I understand its basics, at least.

In this Stanford course we are developing a card matching game, like the game Concentration. Cards are represented by buttons. The normal state (`UIControlStateNormal`) represents the back of the card, while the selected state (`UIControlStateSelected`) represents its front (that is, its contents, a string property called `card.contents`, like "A♣"). If two cards match, they become unplayable, so they get the disabled state (`UIControlStateDisabled`) while already in the selected state. [*See this image for reference.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1gaR.jpg)

In the [Apple documentation about Control States](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_State), we can find this bitmask defining the possible states:

```
enum {
   UIControlStateNormal               = 0,
   UIControlStateHighlighted          = 1 << 0,
   UIControlStateDisabled             = 1 << 1,
   UIControlStateSelected             = 1 << 2,
   UIControlStateApplication          = 0x00FF0000,
   UIControlStateReserved             = 0xFF000000
};
```

At some point, in the code done by the Stanford professor in-lecture, the following code is used to set `card.contents` as the title for both the selected state (the front of the card) and the selected and disabled states combined (a matched card):

```
[cardButton setTitle:card.contents forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[cardButton setTitle:card.contents
            forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled];
```

What I don't understand is, why do we need the first line? I thought the second one would be enough, since it's setting the title for the button by combining two states using an OR, so I interpreted that it already "covers" the case when the card is only in the selected state.

After some tests, I was clearly wrong, so I don't quite understand how iOS handles options stored in bitmasks. Can you help me?

Just one more thing: in the enum declaration above, the first four constants are defined as `0`, `1 << 0`, `1 << 1`, and `1 << 2`, that is, `0`, `1`, `2`, and `4`. Why the developer defined the fifth and the sixth as `0x00FF0000` and `0xFF000000`, and not `1 << 3` and `1 << 4`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to you main question:**

My first guess would be that Apple is comparing the bit masks with an 'exclusive or' (^) rather than a 'bitwise and' (&) when checking which title to display against the state of the button.

When working with binary numbers it helps to look at those numbers in binary form.  The << operator is a left shift.  It takes the first number and shifts it left the second number of spaces.

```
UIControlStateNormal      = 0    = 0000
UIControlStateHighlighted = 1<<0 = 0001
UIControlStateDisabled    = 1<<1 = 0010       
UIControlStateSelected    = 1<<2 = 0100
```

When you set the title for your button you are applying a bit mask to that button for the two states with the 'inclusive or' (|) operator.

```
UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateDisabled = 0010|0100
```

Which works out to be

```
 0010
|0100
 ----
 0110
```

Now when you want to test your state against your the masks of your titles.  When you do this with an & operator you will check that the result is greater than 0 for success and you will be able to have the one title work for multiple states.

```
 0100 // button state is UIControlStateSelected
&0110 // Button title bit mask
 ----
 0100 // This is greater than 0, success

 0000 // button state is UIControlStateNormal
&0110 // Button title bit mask
 ----
 0000 // This is 0, fail
```

Now you can see the problem. Apple initially set a control state to 0, so we cannot use 0 as an indication of failure because in the case where we set a title's bit mask to UIControlStateNormal we get:

```
 0000 // Button state
&0000 // Title bit mask
 ----
 0000 // Failure
```

DOH!

So we use xor (^} to compare the bit masks and 0 is a sign of success, but this means we cannot have multiple states set in the title's bit mask (unless you could somehow have multiple states at the same time.)

```
 0000 // State
^0000 // Mask
 ----
 0000 // results is success

 0100 // State
^0100 // Mask
 ----
 0000 // result is success

 0100 // State
^0010 // Mask
 ----
 0110 // Result fails

 0100 // State
^0110 // Mask
 ----
 0010 // Result will always fail because state can only have a single 1
```

In more modern frameworks, like SpriteKit, you will notice that the documentation and examples start the state definitions at 1<<0 rather than 0 so that this exact problem isn't presented.

**Answer to 'just one more thing':**

As to the second question about the big jump from 1<<2 to 0x00FF0000.

The UIControlStateReserved is a set of bits reserved for internal framework use. It is a marker and everything after that value is off limits.

The UIControlStateApplication is a section of bits that developers can use in their application to expand the defined control states and use in their code or custom controls. It includes all the bits from 0x00FF0000 to 0xFF000000.

Apple puts a buffer between their default control states and the developer defined control states so that future framework updates will not break your application.

You can define a new control state called UIControlStateAwesomeness and assign it to the next available bit 1<<3 because that makes sense, right?
But, then Apple releases iOS 11 and adds 3 new control states. Well, they will add them in order and your app will now have a conflicting state defined in your app.

So, big buffer.  I hope that was not too long winded.

Answer (score -1):

```
1<<0  0x00000001

1<<1  0x00000002

1<<2  0x00000004

1<<3  0x00000008  //not 0x00FF0000

1<<4  0x0000000F  //not 0xFF000000

//those four below in fact are in a kind of substate, like gamestate 
UIControlStateNormal               = 0,          I am stll in game screen
UIControlStateHighlighted          = 1 << 0,     I am stil in game screen
UIControlStateDisabled             = 1 << 1,     I am stil in game screen
UIControlStateSelected             = 1 << 2,     I am stil in game screen
//those two are another substate ,
UIControlStateApplication          = 0x00FF0000,  I am in load screen  
UIControlStateReserved             = 0xFF000000   I am in reserved screen

Then there are some mask_num:
inScreen  =     0x000000FF;
inLoadScreen =  0x00FF0000;
inReScreen   =  oxFF000000;
They can use (nowState& mask_num != 0) to detect now state
```

Well ,all I guess.

Comment: Yes, buy *why* the developer decided to use `0x00FF0000` and `0xFF000000` instead of following the previous pattern?

Comment: @glevco I have some guess in my auswer now